# Web-based REST API browser (explorer, navigator, rambler)?

Tags: api, rest, browser

I'm teaching a lecture about APIs and would love to find a nice, free, Web-based tool to "browse" open REST APIs in a generic way, rendering XML and/or JSON payloads to the screen and speculatively turning anything that looks like a hyperlink into a hyperlink.  So, for example, I could point it to:

http://services.healthindicators.gov/v4/REST.svc/IndicatorDescription/3/IndicatorDescriptionDataCategories/1

and see a nicely-rendered version of the data with clickable links.

Anybody know of a useful resource?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [Apigee Console](https://apigee.com/console/others) is great. It supports a number of predefined APIs and a generic mode for any API. Apigee has a nice snapshot feature where you can make a request and then send a link to anyone and they can view the request/response you made.

There is also [Hurl](http://hurl.it) but it isn't always working.

Comment: Apigee Console is pretty good. Would be nice if it was open source.

Comment: Apigee seems to be discontinued

Answer (score 12):

I really like the Chrome [HTTP Dev Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm) for exploring REST API's.  Works great!

Comment: There is also the PostMan (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) plugin for Chrome, but niether of these really allow jumping around from link to link very well.

Answer (score 4):

I use XML Tree for Chrome.
Highlights and formats XML and has the option to turn URLs into links.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gbammbheopgpmaagmckhpjbfgdfkpadb

Comment: This is very nice!  before marking `answered`, I want to see if anyone can point me to a similar resource for JSON payloads.

Comment: Just look up some keywords. There's even REST clients...
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm

Comment: Postman looks AWESOME. The other solutions here (like Apigee) won't work if you're hosting something behind a firewall -- or in my case, as a development server running on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting way to show web api's

[http://code.google.com/apis/discovery](http://code.google.com/apis/discovery/)/